# Rails migration: how to retrieve current migration version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Is there a good way to retrieve the latest migration version number?

I need to implement a method in a model which behaves differently on and beyond a specific migration version.

I found assume_migrated_upto_version in connection adapter is retrieving version from database but can't find others.

Comment: Why do you have code that behaves differently w.r.t migration versions. Would you please care to explain.

Comment: Right. I added background in the question.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Rails `5.2` and higher:

```
> ApplicationRecord.connection.migration_context.current_version
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
=> 20200510093804

> ApplicationRecord.connection.migration_context.get_all_versions
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
=> [20191005164928,
    20191006111502,
   ...
```

Rails up to `5.1.7`:

```
> ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
=> 20120110085802

> ActiveRecord::Migrator.get_all_versions
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
=> [20111114121610,
    20111115091108,
   ...
```

Comment: **NOTE: `ActiveRecord::Migrator.get_all_versions` does _not_ include pending migrations. It _only_ includes migrations that have already been run.**

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Migrator.get_all_versions` does not work in Rails 6.
Use:
`ApplicationRecord.connection.migration_context.current_version`
`ApplicationRecord.connection.migration_context.get_all_versions`
for Rails 6.

Answer (score 167):

There's a much nicer way: `rails db:migrate:status`

```
up     20120530222941  Create shenanigans
up     20120613030015  *** NO FILE ***
```

Indicating that I've deleted my latest migration file.

Or more simply:

```
> rails db:version
Current version: 20120613030015
```

NOTE: for Rails versions prior to 5.0 replace `rails` with `rake`.

Comment: Thanks. I know that, but I needed to retrieve it programmatically, in a migration.

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 5.x/6.x:

```
puts ApplicationRecord.connection.migration_context.current_version
puts ApplicationRecord.connection.migration_context.get_all_versions
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do this without loading your app you can create a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

root = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
lines = `ls #{root}/db/migrate`
puts lines.split("\n").last.split(" ").last.split("_").first
```

Note the `root` line is because my script is in a `bin` dir

Comment: This does not give you the current version, especially in case you did not ran migrations.