# how to know the latest migration performed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

With `rake db:migrate:status` I can display the status of migrations, but what is the way to display the latest performed?

Comment: Run `rake db:version` and then search into your migrations the one that have the returned timestamp into it's name

Comment: an alternative is to use `ActiveRecord::Migrator.get_all_versions` in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered on Stack Overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8847126/4461194

```
    1.9.3-p551 :001 > ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations"
 => 20150114073202
```